# Example of an additive map $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X$ that is not a differential operator on a Scheme $X$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, schemes, differential-operators

I'm looking for a $S$-Scheme $X$ (with structural morphism $f$) and an additive (or rather $\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}f^{-1} O_S$-linear) endomorphism of sheaves $D: \O_X \to O_X$ which is not a differential operator (as defined in EGA IV, chapter 16).
A morphism $D: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ for some $\O_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ that isn't a differential operator would be interesting, too.

To my surprise I haven't been able to come up with such a thing. The closest I have got is the isomorphism of sheaves of abelian groups $\O_\mathbb{C} \to \O_\mathbb{C} / \underline{\mathbb{C}}$ given by integration ($\O_\mathbb{C}$ being the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\underline{\mathbb{C}}$ the constant sheaf).
However this approach doesn't seem to work for something like $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ because differentiation isn't surjective there.

**A quick definition of differential operators:** A map of sheaves ob abelian groups $D: \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X$ is a differential operators if it factors as $u \circ d^n_{X/S}$ for some $\O_X$-linear $u$ and some $n$.
$d^n_{X/S}: \O_X \to \mathcal{P}^n_{X/S}$ is the map into the sheaf of principal parts $\mathcal{P}^n$ which in turn is defined as $\Delta_{X/S}^{-1} \O_{X \times_S X} / \mathcal{I}^{n+1}$, $\mathcal{I}$ being the kernel of $\Delta^{-1}_{X/S} \O_{X \times_S X} \to \O_X$.
The projection $p_1: X \times_S X$ yields a morphism $\O_X \to \Delta^{-1}_{X/S}\O_{X \times_S X}$ with gives $\mathcal{P}^n_{X/S}$ its structure of $\O_X$-Module. The analogous morphism arising from $p_2$ is $d^n_{X/S}$.
For an more understandable definition, refer to EGA.

**EDIT:** I think it is not implausible to assume that there might no such "non-differential operator" (at least not between sheaves $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathcal{G}$ locally of finite type) on sufficiently nice Schemes: On a real smooth manifold, by peetre's theorem every morphism of sheaves $C^\infty \to C^\infty$ isa differential operator.

Also for $\mathcal{F} = \bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \O_X$ , $D = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial {x_2}^2} + \frac{\partial^3}{\partial {x_3}^3} + \cdots : \mathcal{F} \to \O_X$ is a morphism of sheaves of abelian groups that isn't a differential operator.

Comment: Can you write down the definition of differential operator you're using? It's a lot easier to answer a question when you don't have to find a copy of EGA.

Comment: Any differential operator on $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ is of the form $D=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \frac{d^i}{dx^i}$ and in particular, $\deg D(x^m)\leq  C+m$ for some constant $C$ and all $m$. Easy to construct $\mathbb{C}$-linear maps $D$ from $\mathbb{C}[x]$ to itself not satisfying this property. For example, define a map by $D(x^m)=x^{m^2}$ for all $m$ and extend it linearly.

Comment: @Mohan how would you extend this to a morphism of sheaves?

Comment: Certainly it would.

Comment: @Mohan could you elaborate?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean. A global map defines a sheaf map.

Comment: @Mohan that only works for $A$-linear maps on $\operatorname{Spec} A$ (and between quasi-coherent modules). The point is that this is not an $A$-linear map.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I added a short definition of differential operators.

Comment: @Ben Mohan gave a map $\mathbb{C}[x] \to \mathbb{C}[x]$ (which is **not** $\mathbb{C}[x]$-linear, because that would defeat the purpose). I don't see how to extend this map to a map of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}}$. Note that the universal property of localization is useless here, because the map given is not $\mathbb{C}[x]$-linear.

Comment: To give an example, what should @Mohan's map map $\frac1{z - 2} \in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C} - \{2\})$ to? $\frac1{z^2 - 2}$ is not a section of $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C} - \{2\})$

Comment: Any $\mathcal{O}$-linear map is a differential operator, since $d^0_{X/S} = id_\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @CarlosEsparza I think what Mohan said that a global map defines a sheaf map is right. Locally a section is written as $x^nf/g$ where $f,g$ aren't divisible by $x$, and you can define the map as sending this to $x^{2n}f/g$

Comment: @Ben good idea, but the map you defined is not additive: $\phi(x + x^2) = \phi(x (1 + x)) = x^2 (1 + x) = x^2 + x^3 \neq x^2 + x^4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $X = \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ this corresponds to finding a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $\phi: \mathbb{C}(z) \to \mathbb{C}(z)$, which isn't a differential operator, such that if $\phi(f)$ is divisible by $\frac1{z - a}$ for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$ then so is $f$ (so the possible "domain" of $\phi(f)$ is at least as large as that of $f$, inducing a map of sheaves).

Every element $f/g \in \mathbb{C}(z)$ has a unique representation
$$
\frac{f}{g} = q + \frac{r}{g}
$$
(unique meaning that $q$ and $r/g$ are unique) such that $q \in \mathbb{C}[z]$ and $\deg r <\deg g$. The corresponding map $\lfloor \,\cdot\, \rfloor:  f/g \mapsto q$ satisfies the above conditions if we check that it is not a differential operator.

Every differential operator $D$ on $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ is of the form
$$
f_0 + f_1 \frac{d}{d z} + f_2 \frac{d^2}{d z^2} + \cdots + f_n \frac{d^n}{d z^n}, \quad f_i \in \mathbb{C}[z], f_n \neq 0
$$ (We say that $n$ is the degree of $D$).
Assume $\lfloor \,\cdot\, \rfloor$ is a differential operator. Since $\lfloor z^m \rfloor = z^m$ for $m \geq 0$, we obtain inductively that $f_0$ has to be $1$ and all $f_i$ have to be $0$ for $i \geq 1$ ($D(1) = 1$ implies $f_0 = 1$, then $D(z) = z$ implies $f_1 = 0$ and so on). Hence $\lfloor \,\cdot\, \rfloor = \operatorname{id}$ contradicting $\lfloor z^{-m} \rfloor = 0$ for $m \geq 0$.

**EDIT:**
One can actually observe, that for any field $k$

\begin{equation}
 \{1, x, x^2, \dots\} \cup \left.\left\{\frac{x^k}{p^n} ~\right|~ p ~\text{prime in}~ k[x], n \in \mathbb{N}^+, k < \deg p \right\}
\end{equation}

is a $k$-vector space basis of $k(x)$  via partial fraction decomposition. The $k$-Endomorphisms of $k(z)$ that induce a map of sheaves are those in which basis elements of the form $x^k/p^n$ are mapped to linear combinations of $\{1, x, x^2, \dots\} \cup \{x^\ell / p^m ~|~ m \in \mathbb{N}^+, \ell < \deg p\}$ and basis elements of the form $x^k$ are mapped to polynomials.